# Android 4.0 enable flash in webview

Tags: android, flash, plugins, webview

Is there a certified way of enabling flash in a webview? I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with ICS installed. flash works in my normal browser(the default browser that says `Internet` on the icon). I made an app which has webview in its layout. I load the same page in this `webview` and flash doesn't work. I tried adding the following line in onCreate of my main activity:

```
WebView webView1=(WebView)findViewById(...)
webView1.getSettings().setPluginState(WebView.PluginState.ON);
```

but doesn't work. I also tried using `setPluginsEnabled`([deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginsEnabled%28boolean%29)) but that also didn't work. Also, I set

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

in menifest file in the application tag. But it still doesn't work.

So has anyone made it work? Please help.

Comment: I can assume stock Galaxy S3 browser using some custom view, rather then default WebView available in API. You can try to use $android-sdk-dir$\tools\hierarchyviewer.bat to look exactly which views are used in stock browser (but you need a rooted phone)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a problem related to Javascript not being enabled on the webview?

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score -1):

I had forgotten to enable javascript. Did that and it worked like  a charm.